# Algorithm to draw a specific graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, drawing, draw

I am drawing a graph programmatically. It has the following properties:

> 1 It has not loops
>
> 2 Node can have up to 4 child nodes

I would like to draw it nicely without intersections.

I come up with the following algorithm of doing it:

Draw a graph from right to left, where the rightmost nodes are the lowest and the leftmost node is a root. Before drawing split nodes into levels. Where 0 level is a root, 1 level are the nodes which are children of the root, 2 level are the nodes which are children of the children of the root and so on.

Draw the last level at first (just start with any x position and y position for the first node in the level and increment y position as you draw nodes on the level). When you are done drawing the last level change the x position (each level has a separate x position which is equal for every node in the level, but is different from the every x position in another level) move on to the level before last level. Here for each node we have access to children nodes and know their (children nodes) positions which were set in the previous step. So, just take the position of the child node which has the minimum y value and the position which has the maximum value, average them and the result will be the value for y position of the current node.

Using the same approach draw all the nodes to the left.

Here is an example of the graph which was drawn using the algorithm I presented:
[image]

In this case if we will take the level before the last one all of the nodes on it will have children, but if we take a graph where nodes on the previous (not on the last) levels do not have children, then my algorithm creates intersections. Here is an example:

[image]

Please help me to tackle the issue I am really very stuck.

I am using `d3.js v5.4.0` to draw the graph. To draw the graph I am given the nodes and for each node I am given an array of previous (nodes to the left) and next (nodes to the right) nodes.

Comment: Which language are you using and we will be provided with which data in order to create this above graph ? Thank you.

Comment: @zenwraight, I updated the question. Thank you as well.

Comment: Can you also post an example input and output, like the input and output for the above graph would also work, just trying to understand more here. Thank you

Comment: I think the problem is a lot harder than your algorithm suggests. As a minimum, I would find the level that has the most nodes, and arrange that level first. But even that is probably not enough to guarantee an aesthetically pleasing graph. I expect that there are cases where you'll want additional vertical spacing between nodes even on the level with the most nodes.

Comment: Your definition of the graph properties is a little vague because you don't mention if the graph is directed or undirected. If it's undirected then your second graph doesn't fit because it has loops. These loops are are causing the problem.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, the second graph is drawn incorrectly (and that is the point of the question). There are two nodes under each other. Actually the graph is just an undirected tree.

Comment: @user3386109, the algorithm I come up with above solves all cases except one: when there is at least one node which has two following properties. a) The node does not belong to the last level. b) The node does not have next nodes (next nodes are the same concept as children nodes or nodes to the right connected to the current node under consideration).

Comment: @zenwraight, I am working on Salesforce project and this graph is a custom lightning component there. All the data comes from the Salesforce, so it is almost impossible to show you the actual input. But [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76uedo40/462/) I posted a code which I use to assemble the graph from the data which come from the server side.